# number of appearances of an atribute before a date in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table

[image]

and what I need as an output is to have for each payment the number of payments that have been done with the same credit card.

For example,

for the first payment there would be 0 payments with the same credit card.
for the second payment there would be 1 payment with the same credit card.
for the fifth payment there would be 1 payment with the same credit card.

Does anyone have an idea? thanks

Comment: Huh?  The first AA123 gets a "0", but the first AA456 gets "1"?  Sounds inconsistent.

Comment: If you have an older MariaDB/MySQL, use one `@variable` to count the rows as you go through the table, and another  to see when the hash changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(status = 'approved') OVER (PARTITION BY credit_card_hash 
                                      ORDER BY creation_date) AS payments_with_this_card
FROM sourcetable
```

If current record must NOT be counted then substract 1. Or specify window boundaries BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I am getting a syntax error in this line  **'(partition by CREDIT_CARD_HASH order by creation_date) AS payments_with_this_car'** I don't know what is it, the solution seems fine

Comment: @Mmelo You have not specified your server version. This solution needs MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2+